# Getting an average Python

Tags: python, csv

Basically, I have two csv files. One is the file located here (https://ourworldindata.org/covid-cases). The other is from a bot that runs and grabs hospital wait times. It looks like this:
[Picture of CSV File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEV9Z.png). I'm focusing on Georgia Hospitals specifically, which I know which ones it's recording, but I'm having problems with averaging the wait time across the state each day. I've tried a few different things, but I'm not too familiar with Python. I'm trying to balance it between two different files so that I can compare new cases with wait times. How would I get a list of the average wait times per day for the hospitals in a specific region?

Comment: post your code and attempt

Comment: does `date` and `hospital` have more than one value ?

Comment: You can read your CSV files into Python Pandas DataFrames which has many tools including performing a daily average of data [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23162472/python-pandas-daily-average).  If you post some CSV example data users would be happy to provide more specific guidance.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
average_wait_time = df.groupby(df.datetime.dt.date)['Wait_Time'].mean()
```

Comment: Code dumps without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it works better than what the OP provided.

Comment: That's a fair comment Chris, I know the post could've been better. But I think you're unfair to suggest to delete this post - stack overflow is also about providing alternative answers and then up/down voting. Some questions have plain wrong answers, which receive a lot of downvotes, which in my opinion also provides value, from the point of view of what NOT to do. For me personally, having a working snippet as a starting point works really well. I'm not familiar with authors level of Python, so I wouldn't be able to know where to start (`pip install pandas`?). I genuinely tried to be helpful.